# Sinon, observing different behaviour using Promise.reject() to stub.rejects()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sinon, chai-as-promised

I was having issues running a test (in Node),

I was simulating a promise being rejected, and my code should retry (using [promise-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-retry) if that could be relevant).

When I simulated the rejected promise using `stub.returns(Promise.reject(error)`

I was getting a uncaught error warnings (for my `dummyErrors`), even though I am catching errors where I call my function...

-note, these uncaught errors were only happening in the unit tests not in real calls.

```
const mockedFunction = sinon.stub();

const dummyError = new Error('Document is locked');

mockedFunction.onCall(0).returns(Promise.reject(dummyError));
mockedFunction.onCall(0).returns(Promise.reject(dummyError));
mockedFunction.onCall(0).returns(Promise.reject(dummyError));
mockedFunction.onCall(1).returns(Promise.resolve({approved: true}));
```

I discovered that by changing to use the `stub.rejects()` syntax:

```
mockedFunction.onCall(0).rejects(dummyError);
mockedFunction.onCall(1).rejects(dummyError);
mockedFunction.onCall(2).rejects(dummyError));
mockedFunction.onCall(3).resolves({approved: true});
```

I no longer get the uncaught error warnings.

My issue is solved, however I would like to get a better understand as to why, I looked at the sinon source code and it looks like the implementation of `.rejects` is no different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In promise implementations that are intrinsically detect uncaught error (including V8/Node.js), an error from rejected promise should be caught on same tick, otherwise it triggers `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

This will work fine:

```
let promise = Promise.reject();
promise.catch(() => {});
```

This will result in potentially unhandled promise and trigger a warning:

```
let promise = Promise.reject();
setTimeout(() => {
  promise.catch(() => {});
});
```

If `Promise.reject(dummyError)` isn't chained with `catch(...)` or `then(..., ...)` on same tick, it triggers a warning, while in case of `rejects(dummyError)` a rejected promise is created on function call, so this likely will be true:

```
sinon.spy(Promise, 'reject');
mockedFunction.onCall(0).rejects(dummyError);
expect(Promise.reject).to.have.not.been.called;
mockedFunction();
expect(Promise.reject).to.have.been.called;
```

An alternative to `rejects(dummyError)` is:

```
mockedFunction.onCall(0).callsFake(() => Promise.reject(dummyError))
```